# load remote content using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the script to load remote content and display in a div

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceUrl) {
$(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://remote.com/abc.html");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:loadContent('#content', '');">Link 1</a>
<div id="content">content will be loaded here</div>
asfasdfasf
</body>
```

But it seems there is something security blocking the script about the cross domain ajax, i use xampp as my localhost web server

Error message at chrome console

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

i've searched some solution such as add

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

but not work.

Any fastest way to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of [same origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), it does not allow a page to make a Ajax request to a resource hosted in a different domain.

Since it looks like you are dealing with an HTML content, the only solution is to use [CORS](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS&ei=rSUPUpAbz4msB6TagIAL&usg=AFQjCNEy-W8wmoOH0v6DZp-591zizBhAYw&bvm=bv.50768961,d.bmk) if the hosting server supports it